# RN Firebase: Request passwordless sign-in on mobile, open link on PC, get signed-in on mobile?

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, react-native-firebase

I've successfully set up a passwordless sign-in flow on mobile (using [dynamic links](https://rnfirebase.io/dynamic-links/usage)). It works on iOS and Android, as long as the sign-in link is opened on the same mobile device.

I would like to support the scenario where users **sign-in on mobile, but open the link on their PC**. Is this even possible?

When clicking the link on the PC, I currently see an empty page, with the URL configured in my `ActionCodeSettings`:

```
const actionCodeSettings: FirebaseAuthTypes.ActionCodeSettings = {
    handleCodeInApp: true,
    url: 'https://the-url-i-see',
    iOS: {
      bundleId: '...',
    },
    android: {
      packageName: '...',
      installApp: true,
    },
  }
```

Which parts are missing on my end?

**UPDATE**

I'm one step closer: I created an `index.html` to be served via `https://the-url-i-see`:

```
if (firebase.auth().isSignInWithEmailLink(window.location.href)) {
  email = window.prompt('Please provide your email for confirmation');
  firebase.auth().signInWithEmailLink(email, window.location.href).then(() => {
    console.log('Sign-in successful')
  }).catch(e => {
    console.error('Sign-in failed', e)
  })
}
```

What works now:

- Requesting a sign-in on mobile sends an email link
- Opening the link on PC navigates to the above `index.html`
- After confirming the email through the prompt:

  - Login is successful: 'Sign-in successful' in console
  - **New user created/visible in Firebase Console**

What is still missing:

Mobile app is not notified about the sign-in (specifically, `onAuthStateChanged` handler is not firing).

Comment: `onAuthStateChanged` will not fire. So it's better to have user click a button and do user reload `auth().currentUser.reload()`

Comment: @vinayr Could you elaborate why `onAuthStateChanged` will not fire? Where should the user "click a button"? On PC/web or on mobile?

Comment: afaik firebase doesn't provide the feature of triggering `onAuthStateChanged` on one device while opening link on another device. To overcome this limitation you can have a button on your mobile app, something like 'Proceed', where you can reload user and check if authenticated. Or you can just show some message forcing users to click the link on the same device. It's a design decision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meanwhile I've learned that this is not how Firebase Auth works. My new understanding, overly simplified:

- A sign-in link is like a ticket
- The ticket can be used to sign-in once
- Signing in is specific to one `firebase.auth()` realm (which will trigger `onAuthStateChanged` in this realm)
- In my case: one auth realm = one device

TL;DR: Passwordless sign-in across devices is not supported out-of-the-box